# How to create a "common" object by click?

Tags: javascript

Hello There is a problem, I need to create a "common object" configuration when clicked, so that it could be used in other objects. But when I create it, it is not visible outside of the f-tion of the click (
What is the problem and how i can fix it?

This is my code

```
const confirmButton = document.getElementById('confirm');
let gameSettings;

confirmButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const countOfPlayers = document.getElementById('player').value;
  const countOfCards = document.getElementById('card').value;
  const countOfNumbers = document.getElementById('nums').value;
  gameSettings = {
    countOfPlayers,
    countOfCards,
    countOfNumbers
  }; // Create object
  e.target.parentElement.remove();
});

class Player {
  constructor(name, cards) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cards = cards || [];
  }
}

class Card {
  constructor(numbers) {
    this.numbers = numbers;
  }
}

class Game {
  constructor() {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(Game, gameSettings); // here it does not see gameSettings, gives out issue Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined, this is because gameSettings equal to undefined.
    this.win = false;
  }

  getPlayers() {
    console.log(this.countOfPlayers);
  }
}
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ujqe9akL/11/

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `gamesettings` the `prototype` of the `Game.prototype`, bacause the methods of `Game` class are put in the `Game.prototype`,

```
class Game {
  constructor() {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(Game.prototype, gameSettings); 
    this.win = false;
  }

  getPlayers() {
    console.log(this.countOfPlayers);
  }
}
```

And I advise against this approach, try to make default parameters or options, don't put your settings in the prototype.

Comment: Yep,thanks. Its works. But the default object will also have to be inheritance in some way.